# Only one item of my file.bib appears when I compile

Tags: biblatex

This is my `.bib` file:

```
@Book{Carrega1989,
    title     = {Théorie des corps: La règle et le compas},
    publisher = {Hermann},
    year      = {1989},
    author    = {J.C.Carrega},
}
@Book{marcay,
    title     = {Constructions à la règle et au compas},
    publisher = {Département de Mathématiques d’Orsay, Université Paris-Sud, France},
    author    = {Fran\c{c}ois, DE MAR\c{C}AY},
}
@Book{Krop,
    title     = {La quadrature du cercle et le nombre \pi},
    publisher = {Éditions Ellipses, Paris},
    year      = {2005},
    author    = {Krop André}
}

@online{or,
    author    = {Philippe Picart},

    title =  {Le nombre d'or},
    url = {http://trucsmaths.free.fr/nombre_d_or.htm},
urldate = today,
}
@Book{Mutaf,
    title     = {\'{E}quations algébriques et théorie de Galois},
    publisher = {Vuibert},
    year      = {1980},
    author    = {Claude Mutafian},
}
@online{Dec,
    author    = {Patrice Debart},

    title =  {Descartes et les Mathématiques},
    url = {http://debart.pagesperso-orange.fr/},
    urldate = today,
}
```

This is my bibliography style:

```
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=verbose,sorting=none]{biblatex}
\bibliography{monref}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\addbibresource{monref.bib}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{%
    \ifboolexpr{ test {\ifentrytype{book}} or test {\ifentrytype{mvbook}}
        or test {\ifentrytype{collection}} or test {\ifentrytype{mvcollection}}
        or test {\ifentrytype{reference}} or test {\ifentrytype{mvreference}} }
    {\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}[book]}
    {\ifentrytype{online}
        {\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}[online]}
        {\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}[article]}}%
    \usebeamertemplate{bibliography item}}
\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
{\list{}
    {\settowidth{\labelwidth}{\usebeamertemplate{bibliography item}}%
        \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
        \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
        \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
        \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
        \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}}
{\endlist}
{\item}
```

and

```
\begin{frame}[noframenumbering,plain,allowframebreaks]{Références}
\printbibliography
\end{frame}
```

What is the problem? Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Welcome, this is an English language site. Please rephrase your question.

Comment: Here is the automatic translator I use to participate here: https://www.deepl.com/translator To participate in French, there is https://texnique.fr/osqa/

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. albert's request is a fair one, please do if you can. As to the question, have you actually cited somewhere in your document the other items which don't appear in your bibliography? If you want every item in your bib file to show, irrespective of citation, you can use `\nocite{*}` before `\printbibliography`.

Comment: i have this message : Missing $ inserted. \end{frame} widh \nocite{*}

Comment: In the `title` field of the Krop entry, you must switch to math mode to handle `\pi` properly.

Comment: The `author` field of the Krop entry should almost certainly be `author = {Krop, André}`. (Note the comma.)

Comment: The `author` field of the Carrega1989 entry should almost certainly be `author  = {J. C. Carrega},`. (Note the extra spaces.)

Comment: Since you provide the instruction `\addbibresource{monref.bib}`, you should get rid of `\bibliography{monref}`.

Comment: thinks Mico and Kurt

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues with your shown code.

In the `bib` file you had some empty lines I deleted, I corrected the missing `$\pi$` to get `\pi` printed in math mode, I changed all authors to `familyname, firstname` and corrected the `urldate` in your entries `or` and `Dec` to `urldate = {2018-12-02}`.

I deleted your line `\bibliography{monref}` (not needed for `biblatex` if you also have `\addbibresource{monref.bib}`) and I completed your code with class `beamer` and a missing `\nocite{*}` to get all bib entries printed ...

So the following MWE

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{Carrega1989,
    title     = {Théorie des corps: La règle et le compas},
    publisher = {Hermann},
    year      = {1989},
    author    = {Carrega, J. C.},
}
@Book{marcay,
    title     = {Constructions à la règle et au compas},
    publisher = {Département de Mathématiques d’Orsay, Université Paris-Sud, France},
    author    = {Fran\c{c}ois, DE MAR\c{C}AY},
}
@Book{Krop,
    title     = {La quadrature du cercle et le nombre $\pi$},
    publisher = {Éditions Ellipses, Paris},
    year      = {2005},
    author    = {Krop, André}
}
@online{or,
    author  = {Picart, Philippe},
    title   =  {Le nombre d'or},
    url     = {http://trucsmaths.free.fr/nombre_d_or.htm},
    urldate = {2018-12-02},
}
@Book{Mutaf,
    title     = {\'{E}quations algébriques et théorie de Galois},
    publisher = {Vuibert},
    year      = {1980},
    author    = {Claude Mutafian},
}
@online{Dec,
    author  = {Debart, Patrice},
    title   =  {Descartes et les Mathématiques},
    url     = {http://debart.pagesperso-orange.fr/},
    urldate = {2018-12-02},
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=verbose,sorting=none]{biblatex}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{%
    \ifboolexpr{ test {\ifentrytype{book}} or test {\ifentrytype{mvbook}}
        or test {\ifentrytype{collection}} or test {\ifentrytype{mvcollection}}
        or test {\ifentrytype{reference}} or test {\ifentrytype{mvreference}} }
    {\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}[book]}
    {\ifentrytype{online}
        {\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}[online]}
        {\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}[article]}}%
    \usebeamertemplate{bibliography item}}
\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
{\list{}
    {\settowidth{\labelwidth}{\usebeamertemplate{bibliography item}}%
        \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
        \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
        \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
        \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
        \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}}
{\endlist}
{\item}

\usetheme{Berkeley}


\title{The Title}
\author{The Author}
\institute{The Institute}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \maketitle
\end{frame}

\nocite{*}
\begin{frame}[noframenumbering,plain,allowframebreaks]{Références}
  \printbibliography
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

gives you the resulting bibliography:

[image: resulting bibliography]

## UPDATE:

Because it is not clear for me, which is the correct order for your used name `Fran\c{c}ois, DE MAR\c{C}AY` test the following bib file containing three possibilities:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{marcay,
    title     = {Constructions à la règle et au compas},
    publisher = {Département de Mathématiques d’Orsay, Université Paris-Sud, France},
    author    = {Fran\c{c}ois, DE MAR\c{C}AY},
}
@Book{marcaya,
    title     = {Constructions à la règle et au compas},
    publisher = {Département de Mathématiques d’Orsay, Université Paris-Sud, France},
    author    = {MAR\c{C}AY, Fran\c{c}ois DE },
}
@Book{marcayb,
    title     = {Constructions à la règle et au compas},
    publisher = {Département de Mathématiques d’Orsay, Université Paris-Sud, France},
    author    = {DE MAR\c{C}AY, Fran\c{c}ois },
}
\end{filecontents*}
```

Then you can decide to use the correct one:

[image]

Comment: I have slightly edited your answer: `urldate` must be given in ISO date format, i.e. `YYYY-MM-DD`, `YYYY/MM/DD` will not work.

Comment: Now that I think about it `author    = {Fran\c{c}ois, DE MAR\c{C}AY},` is very probably also wrong and should be `author    = {Fran\c{c}ois de Mar\c{c}ay},` instead.